# Undefined: Client Nametag

Tags: node.js, discord.js

It return "undefined" when the bot tries to send `client.user.nametag`.

```
if (message.content === "j!info") {
    Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor(client.user.nametag, client.user.avatarURL())
    message.channel.send(Embed)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord.js does not have a `client.user.nametag` property.
You might be looking for [client.user.tag](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=tag) instead.